# iPhone, how can I provide a simple tutorial for my app where screens are pushed etc?

Tags: iphone

I'm looking for a simple way to provide a tutorial for my app.

I want the tutorial to show something on screen and be moved to the next screen as they move through the tutorial.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an NSTimer in your AppDelegate to automatically present views over a period of time, in sync with a voiceover

Comment: Wow that sounds like it could be complicated, what about showing the keypad etc ??

Comment: Take screenshots, put them in UIImageView objects inside a navigation controller, and just start pushing the views onto the stack

Comment: So your mean, build up dummy screens and add my own controls on top for the tutorial?

Comment: Why not use a .h264 encoded tutorial video, in either portrait or landscape?  That way you can have audio and video all in one?